# Detect what audio file my plugin is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using a plugin called Amazing Audio Player to play some audio files (mp3).

I have two elements on my website that I'd like to have changed as the song changes (ex. lyrics, band info).

I am a college student learning javascript and jquery, and doing this for a final project so I only have basic knowledge.

How can I write a script that detects whats being played by the plugin?

Plugin website: https://amazingaudioplayer.com/

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PirateX
Amazing audio player js: https://jsfiddle.net/4fvap8hj/

init audio player js: https://jsfiddle.net/zqbLnqb6/

HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/jrk1awjw/